# When many Akka Actors send messages to one actor, how to cleanly handle inheritance of inner Command classes

Tags: java, oop, akka

In akka-typed, the convention is to create Behavior classes with static inner classes that represent the messages that they receive. Heres a simple example

```java
public class HTTPCaller extends AbstractBehavior<HTTPCaller.MakeRequest> {

  public interface Command {}

  // this is the message the HTTPCaller receives
  public static final class MakeRequest implements Command { 
    public final String query;
    public final ActorRef<Response> replyTo;

    public MakeRequest(String query, ActorRef<Response> replyTo) {
      this.query = query;
      this.replyTo = replyTo;
    }
  }
  
  // this is the response message
  public static final class Response implement Command {
    public final String result;

    public Response(String result) {
      this.result = result;
    }
  }

  public static Behavior<Command> create() {
    return Behaviors.setup(HTTPCaller::new);
  }

  private HTTPCaller(ActorContext<Command> context) {
    super(context);
  }

  @Override
  public Receive<Command> createReceive() {
    return newReceiveBuilder()
               .onMessage(MakeRequest.class, this::onMakeRequest).build();
  }

  private Behavior<MakeRequest> onMakeRequest(MakeRequest message) {
    String result = // make HTTP request here using message.query
    message.replyTo.tell(new Response(result));
    return Behaviors.same();
  }
}
```

Let's say that 20 other actors send `MakeRequest` messages to the single HTTPCaller actor. Now, each of these other actors have inner classes that implement their own `Command`. Since `MakeRequest` is being used by all 20 classes it must be a subtype of all 20 of those actors' `Command` inner interface.

This is not ideal. I'm wondering what the Akka way of getting around this is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no requirement that a message (e.g. a command) which an actor sends (except for messages to itself...) have to conform to that actor's incoming message type.  The commands sent to the `HTTPCaller` actor only have to (and in this case only do) extend `HTTPCaller.Command`.

So imagine that we have something like

```java
public class SomeOtherActor extends AbstractBehavior<SomeOtherActor.Command> {
  public interface Command;

  // yada yada yada
    ActorRef<HTTPCaller.Command> httpCallerActor = ...
    httpCallerActor.tell(new HTTPCaller.MakeRequest("someQuery", getContext().getSystem().ignoreRef());
}
```

In general, when defining messages which are sent in reply, those are not going to extend the message type of the sending actor.  In `HTTPCaller`, for instance, `Response` probably shouldn't `implements Command`: it can be a standalone class (alternatively, if it *is* something that might be received by the `HTTPCaller` actor, it should be handled in the receive builder).

My code above does bring up one question: if `Response` is to be received by `SomeOtherActor`, how can it extend `SomeOtherActor.Command`?

The solution there is message adaptation: a function to convert a `Response` to a `SomeOtherActorCommand`.  For example

```java
// in SomeOtherActor

// the simplest possible adaptation:
public static final class ResponseFromHTTPCaller implements Command {
  public final String result;

  public ResponseFromHTTPCaller(HTTPCaller.Response response) {
    result = response.result;
  }

// at some point before telling the httpCallerActor...
// apologies if the Java lambda syntax is messed up...
ActorRef<HTTPCaller.Response> httpCallerResponseRef =
  getContext().messageAdapter(
    HTTPCaller.Response.class,
    (response) -> { new ResponseFromHTTPCaller(response) }
  );

httpCallerActor.tell(new HTTPCaller.MakeRequest("someQuery", httpCallerResponseRef);
```

There is also the ask pattern, which is more useful for one-shot interactions between actors where there's a timeout.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I think this `messageAdapter()` is just what I was missing